# Add 2D matrices in C

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, return, addition

I am trying to add two 2D matrices and I'm having some trouble with the pointers I guess. The algorithm itself is no problem obviously but I want to have it as a return function, all solutions I found so far didn't do that. This is my code right now, it fails at the function call:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

float **addMatrix(float **m1, float **m2, int x, int y){
    float m3[x][y];
    int i, j;
    for (i=0;i<x;i++){
        for (j=0;j<y;j++){
            m3[i][j]=m1[i][j]+m2[i][j];
        }
    }
    return m3;  
}

int main(){
    int x=3,y=3;
    float m1[x][y], m2[x][y];
    float **m3 = addMatrix(m1, m2, x, y);
    return 0;
}

Warnings: 
    In function 'addMatrix':
    [Warning] return from incompatible pointer type
    [Warning] function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]
    In function 'main':
    [Warning] passing argument 1 of 'addMatrix' from incompatible pointer type
    [Note] expected 'float **' but argument is of type 'float (*)[(sizetype)(y)]'
    [Warning] passing argument 2 of 'addMatrix' from incompatible pointer type
    [Note] expected 'float **' but argument is of type 'float (*)[(sizetype)(y)]'
```

Comment: A two-dimensional array is not a pointer-to-pointer.

Comment: See [Arrays](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/), section "Arrays as parameters".

Comment: What compiler warnings and errors do you get? In `main()` you can't re-assign `m3` in this way.

Comment: @WeatherVane  ok I changed the line to float **m3 = addMatrix(m1, m2, x, y); now it compiles at least I added the warnings in the main post.

Comment: It is of no use returning a pointer to `m3` because `m3` is a local stack variable and it goes out of scope as soon as the function ends.

Comment: @WeatherVane so it's pretty much just impossible to return a matrix as I want to?

Comment: You would either have to pass it as a function argument, or allocate memory for it within the function, if you wish to return an array (pointer) that can actually be used.

Comment: @WeatherVane ok I understand, thank you very much for answering!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, an array of values (e.g. `int m1[3][3]`) is not equivalent to an array of pointers to `type int` (e.g. `int **m1;`).

Next, when passing arrays to a function (as opposed to an array of pointers to type), you must pass every dimension except the number of rows. (the first one). So in your case you can either pass them all, `addMatrix (float m1[3][3]...)`, or pass the number of columns `addMatrix (float m1[][3]...)`)

Before you attempt to add anything in C, you must initialize or set the value of what you are adding together. When you pass `m1` and `m2` to addMatrix, they are uninitialized. (it will be like a box of chocolates). Initialize and set the values for `m1` and `m2` before calling `addMatrix`.

You cannot return an array created locally within a function unless you are returning a *pointer to a dynamically allocated block of memory*. All returns in C are single values (which can be a single pointer to something more complex) Here your `return type` for `addMatrix` is wrong. You need to pass `m3` to `addMatrix` to hold the results of the addition. Therefore, the return may as well be `void` (or some other single value to represent success/failure). e.g.:

```
void addMatrix (float m3[][3], float m1[][3], float m2[][3], int x)
```

Lastly, and I know I have probably forgotten something, unless you are attempting to use variable length arrays, your declarations for the arrays must be with constant values, not variables. The simplest way to do this, and have a way to conveniently change the value throughout the code, is to create a `#define` for the dimensions at the beginning of the code.

Putting that all together, you could do something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define DIMXY 3

void addMatrix (float m3[][DIMXY], float m1[][DIMXY], float m2[][DIMXY], int x)
{
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < DIMXY; j++) {
            m3[i][j] = m1[i][j] + m2[i][j];
        }
    }
}

int main ()
{
    int i, j, x = 3;
    float m1[DIMXY][DIMXY] = {{0}};  /* always initialize arrays to zero */
    float m2[DIMXY][DIMXY] = {{0}};
    float m3[DIMXY][DIMXY] = {{0}};

    /* now fill m1 & m2 -- otherwise "what are you adding?" */
    for (i = 0; i < x; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < DIMXY; j++) {
            m1[i][j] = i + j + 1;
            m2[i][j] = m1[i][j] + 4;
        }

    addMatrix (m3, m1, m2, x);

    printf ("\n Printing m1\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < DIMXY; j++)
            printf ( "  %4.1f", m1[i][j]);
        putchar ('\n');
    }

    printf ("\n Printing m2\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < DIMXY; j++)
            printf ( "  %4.1f", m2[i][j]);
        putchar ('\n');
    }

    printf ("\n Printing m3 after addMatrix\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < DIMXY; j++)
            printf ( "  %4.1f", m3[i][j]);
        putchar ('\n');
    }


    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/arr_add_2d

 Printing m1

   1.0   2.0   3.0
   2.0   3.0   4.0
   3.0   4.0   5.0

 Printing m2

   5.0   6.0   7.0
   6.0   7.0   8.0
   7.0   8.0   9.0

 Printing m3 after addMatrix

   6.0   8.0  10.0
   8.0  10.0  12.0
  10.0  12.0  14.0
```

If by chance your intent was to use *variable length arrays*, then your code would look something like this:

```
void addMatrix (float m3[][3], float m1[][3], float m2[][3], int x, int y)
{
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < y; j++) {
            m3[i][j] = m1[i][j] + m2[i][j];
        }
    }
}

int main ()
{
    int i, j, x = 3, y = 3;
    float m1[x][y];  /* cannot initialize variable size objects */
    float m2[x][y];
    float m3[x][y];

    /* now fill m1 & m2 -- otherwise "what are you adding?" */
    for (i = 0; i < x; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < y; j++) {
            m1[i][j] = i + j + 1;
            m2[i][j] = m1[i][j] + 4;
        }

    addMatrix (m3, m1, m2, x, y);
```